# Error in Adding ScreenShot to Pytest Html Report

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm unable to add Screen-Shot of failed Scanerios in desired html report.
What I did is just moved creation of html report in other desired folder and i'm getting error that Screen Shot is not getting placed in HTML report
below is my code for ScreenShot present in conftest

```
@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item):
    """
        Extends the PyTest Plugin to take and embed screenshot in html report, whenever test fails.
        :param item:
        """
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])

    if report.when == 'call' or report.when == "setup":
        xfail = hasattr(report, 'wasxfail')
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
            file_name = report.nodeid.replace("::", "_") + ".png"
            _capture_screenshot(file_name)
            if file_name:
                html = '<div><img src="%s" alt="screenshot" style="width:304px;height:228px;" ' \
                       'onclick="window.open(this.src)" align="right"/></div>' % file_name
                extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html(html))
        report.extra = extra


def _capture_screenshot(name):
        driver.get_screenshot_as_file(name)
```